# MVC 3 on IIS 7 returns 404 for MVC extensionless url requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7

Our website is a mix of asp.net web-forms and MVC 3. The website is developed in web-forms, except for a separate MVC application that is stored in a separate Directory in the root of the website and having its own web.config. The web-forms pages (aspx) are served properly by the IIS 7 server, but MVC url's are returning **404 - File or directory not found.**

For example, say the website is **www.abc.com** and the MVC application is accessed using **www.abc.com/aaa/controller/action**, where **aaa** is the root directory for the MVC application and contains its own web.config. The web-forms url (say www.abc.com/feedback.aspx) is working but, the MVC URL's (say (www.abc.com/aaa/Controller/Action) are returning 404.

I have confirmed from my shared hosting provider, that the website is running over **.net 4 Integrated pipeline Mode** application pool, so extensionless url's should be handled by the IsapiModule by default, without requiring any extra configuration for the same.

One doubt that crops in my mind is whether the MVC application root folder (**aaa** in above example) should be converted to a separate application ?

Any guesses, to resolve the above MVC url issue?

Comment: I'd agree that you probably need to make "aaa" an virtual application since it essentially is with it's own web.config.

Answer (score 0):

[asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) and [webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms) share the routing system. You should make a Hybrid WebApp, part WebForm and MVC. I did something similar recently here, where the [webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms) is the main app and the MVC is the nested one. In this case, you must have only one global.asax and a single web.config for the entire site. The MVC could live at the same directory as the WebForm, but only with they share stuff.

I followed this guide from **[Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx)** to make this work.

Comment: The website (web-forms) is developed by someone else, and I had developed a separate MVC application. So, making hybrid web app is not likely a solution that I would consider at this stage.

Comment: Then you have to put each app in a separete virtual directory, and maybe, make a third one to manage Authentication and redirection, given that they will be cross domain application.

Comment: The MVC application is meant only for internal use and has its separate Authentication modules. I am not sure about the redirection part, but there is only one domain in question here.

Comment: Given that they dont share the same AppDomain, theres no way to make this work as you expect. Create a new virtual directory, put the Mvc app there, and then redirect from the WebForm to this one.

Answer (score 0):

The hosting provider uses [WebsitePanel](http://www.websitepanel.net/) , through which I was able to create a Virtual Directory for the folder containing the MVC application. The MVC URL's are now being routed to the Isapi handler and not returning 404(file not found) any more. So, I guess I will close this topic here.

In short, creating a virtual directory for the MVC application resolved the issue.